# What are all of Rin's cats that have names?

Tags: little-busters

Of all the cats that have names, which cat is given which name (provide a picture or a description of its features)? How did Rin come up with these names?

[image: Which cat is which?]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rin names her cats after famous people.

These are the ones I know of (collected from [TVTropes](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/VisualNovel/LittleBusters), the [*Little Busters!* Wiki](http://littlebusters.wikia.com/wiki/Rin_Natsume), [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Little_Busters!_characters#Original_members), and other sources):

1. Dorj (a nickname of [Asashōryū Akinori](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asash%C5%8Dry%C5%AB_Akinori)):

   [image: A yellow-brown cat, very fat and large.]
2. Gates ([Bill Gates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bill_Gates)): *Unknown appearance.*
3. Fabre ([Jean-Henri Fabre](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean-Henri_Fabre)): A rather chubby cat.
4. Einstein ([Albert Einstein](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albert_Einstein)): *Unknown appearance.*
5. Lennon ([John Lennon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Lennon)), on the right:

   [image: A small, white-furred kitten]
6. Tezuka ([Osamu Tezuka](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osamu_Tezuka)): A shiny, blue (female) cat.
7. Schumacher ([Michael Schumacher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Schumacher)): *Unknown appearance.*
8. Hitler ([Adolf Hitler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adolf_Hitler)): A spotted cat.
9. Audrey ([Audrey Hepburn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audrey_Hepburn), I think): *Unknown appearance.*
10. Jackie ([Jackie Chan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jackie_Chan)): *Unknown appearance.*
11. Aristotle ([no first name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aristotle)): *Unknown appearance.*
12. Isoroku ([Isoroku Yamamoto](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isoroku_Yamamoto)): A small, grey kitten.
13. Cobain ([Kurt Cobain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurt_Cobain)): *Unknown appearance.*
14. Fedor ([Fedor Emelianenko](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fedor_Emelianenko)): *Unknown appearance.*
15. Hokusai ([Katsushika Hokusai](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hokusai)): *Unknown appearance.*
16. Yusaku, or Matsuda ([Yusaku Matsuda](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yusaku_Matsuda)): *Unknown appearance.*

However, you will notice how many are labelled "unknown" above; these are ones whose appearance I'm unsure of. These appear to be all of the cats she's named, but as she does not always name them directly or identify which one is which, determining their actual appearance is not always possible*.

<sub>* If I discover more appearances, I will add them upon discovery.</sub>

Answer (score 6):

The following list is mostly from [TVTropes](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/VisualNovel/LittleBusters?from=Main.LittleBusters), with a couple of extras added in. Note that all of them are named after famous people in history.

> Lennon, Dorj, Hitler, Audrey, Kobain, Tezuka, Gates, Einstein, Fedor, Aristotle, Hokusai, Jackie Chan, and Matsuda.

It is well-known that Lennon is the white cat which is often on her shoulder, and Dorj is the particularly fat cat which is occasionally confused for a seal. However, most of these are going to be difficult to identify. They may not be described anywhere individually. Because of that, a complete answer is likely to be very difficult.

Also, Rin seems to get more cats every time the series is adapted, so a complete answer may be very difficult. The above list only includes ones which are present in the visual novel.

Answer (score 2):

In the anime, only the following four pet cats of Rin can be identified with a name: (I put the episode number when we first learned of their identity in parentheses):

Lennon (ep 1):

[image: Lennon]

Isoroku (ep 2):

[image: Isoroku]

Fabre (ep 4):

[image: Fabre]

Tezuka (ep 20):

[image: Tezuka]

Other names were mentioned, and many more cats were shown onscreen, but we weren't told which was which, not even in the case of Dorj.

As for the visual novel, [this neta collection](http://brightbell.main.jp/kipima/game/LittleBusters/lb_koneta.html) lists these twenty names for Rin's cats:

1. [Lennon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Lennon)
2. [Einstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albert_Einstein)
3. [Akutagawa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ry%C5%ABnosuke_Akutagawa)
4. [Aristotle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aristotle)
5. [Irfan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C4%B0lhan_Mans%C4%B1z)
6. [Audrey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audrey_Hepburn)
7. [Guts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guts_Ishimatsu)
8. [Gates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bill_Gates)
9. [Cobain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurt_Cobain)
10. [Jackie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jackie_Chan)
11. [Schumacher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Schumacher)
12. [Tezuka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osamu_Tezuka)
13. [Hitler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adolf_Hitler) ([Isoroku](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isoroku_Yamamoto))
14. [Fedor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fedor_Emelianenko)
15. [Fabre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean-Henri_Fabre)
16. [Hokusai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hokusai)
17. [Mendelssohn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Felix_Mendelssohn)
18. [Yuusaku](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yusaku_Matsuda)
19. [Miles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miles_Davis)
20. [Dorj](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asash%C5%8Dry%C5%AB_Akinori)